# Is there an iPhone drop-in charging cradle?

Tags: iphone, hardware-recommendation, charging

Is there a third-party accessory that plugs into the iPhone's dock connector and lets you literally *drop* it into a (supplied by the same manufacturer) cradle to charge by way of electrical contact?

This question is NOT asking about a SYNCING cradle.  ONLY charging is sufficient.

This question is NOT about "charging pads" that work without electrical contact by way of RF or magnetic flux.

Some models of blackberry have small electrical contacts on the bottom of the device that allow it to be "dropped" into a charging dock.  Is there an iPhone accessory that enables the same kind of behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You'd want something like this charger called [Elevation Dock](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/hop/elevation-dock-the-best-dock-for-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this
http://amzn.to/AjoFSV

or this (which syncs as well but is optional)
http://amzn.to/wu9mMH